# .BAT file code on when control command appears

Tags: mysql, sql, batch-file, cmd, sqlcmd

I have created a batch file that should upload the data into the database.
After I enter the database name and password, a command appears `control =` where we enter the `.ctl` file.

Unfortunately I am not able to find the command that enters the CTL file name.

Any help would be appreciated.

Batch file code:

```
@ECHO OFF 
sqlldr database_name/password@username
pause
SEC_LOAD.ctl
pause
```

This is the output in console window:

```
sqlldr database_name/password@username

control =
SQL*Loader-287: No control file name specified.

pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

All I need is to call file `SEC_LOAD.ctl` when `control =` appears in cmd, instead it is called after the control command.

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle documentation for the sqlldr command line appears to say that the control file and log file can be specified on the command line.

```
sqlldr scott/tiger control=ulcase1.ctl log=ulcase1.log
```

If you are using MySQL, are you going to use `mysqlimport`?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question, but the SQL code is perfectly fine to load the data in the database. All I need is a way to to call my file when "control = " appears in the CMD

Comment: @AnkitDalal You can't use the user interactive mode of `sqlldr.exe` because it is executed by a batch file and not by you from within a command prompt window. You have to specify all the options `sqlldr.exe` requires for this task on the command line so that it does not prompt the user at all for missing options. That is quite clear written by [lit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447901/lit). I recommend to read the documentation of `sqlldr` because it is always advisable to read the documentation of an executable before using it.